# How to reorder elements in a formula?

Tags: r

Suppose I have this formula: `formula <- y~d|z|x`. I want to reorder it to `y~x|d|z`. How do I do this?

I've tried:

```
as.Formula(formula(formula,lhs=1,rhs=3),formula(formula, lhs = 1, rhs = 1)[c(-2,-1)])
```

It obviously doesn't work.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi It doesn't need to be restricted to a particular package. The logic is that, I need to reorder terms in the original formula. formula() is a function, and my formula is also called "formula", which is a variable.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Two packages need different forms of formulae. I'm writing another package, so the two different forms better be the same.

Comment: @LudwigGershwin; can you give the packages please. The formula with two bars like that is non-standard. So the packages likely have functions to parse these. Also need to check wether the formula interface in these packages take other symbols beyond the vertical bar?

Comment: @user20650 Thank you for your response, but the problem is solved. I'm looking at `ivreg` package.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Well, I think my purpose is clear enough. No offence but my question doesn't need too much explanation.

Answer (score 4):

**1) all.vars** Extract the variables using `all.vars`, reorder them and then use `reformulate` to put them  back together.  This approach assumes that the components are single variables but the other alternatives allow general expressions as components.

```
fo <- y~d|z|x

v <- all.vars(fo)
reformulate(paste(v[c(4, 2, 3)], collapse = "|"), v[1], env = environment(fo))
## y ~ x | d | z
```

**2) strings** Convert to a string, split and reorder the components and then convert back to a formula.  The last line is the same as in (1).  The input `fo` was defined in (1).

```
s <- fo |>
  format() |>
  strsplit("[~|]") |>
  unlist()
reformulate(paste(s[c(4, 2, 3)], collapse = "|"), s[1], env = environment(fo))
## y ~ x | d | z
```

**3) Formula**   Using the Formula package we can write the following. The input `fo` was defined in (1).

```
library(Formula)
formula(Formula(fo), lhs = 1, rhs = c(3, 1, 2))
## y ~ x | d | z
```

Answer (score 1):

```
formula <- y~d|z|x

a <- formula[[3]][[2]]
b <- formula[[3]][[3]]

formula[[3]][[2]][[2]] <- b
formula[[3]][[2]][[3]] <- a[[2]]
formula[[3]][[3]] <- a[[3]]

formula
#y ~ x | d | z
```

It's a bit difficult (but possible) to generalize because `|` is a function (and there are two nested calls) and you need to deal with the call tree.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried `as.Formula(formula(formula,lhs=1,rhs=3),formula(formula, lhs = 0, rhs = 1),formula(formula, lhs = 0, rhs = 2))`, it works also.